# Creating a custom Library Function in R

Tags: r, function, package

I would like to install/load packages from a different location that is default. I dont have admin privileges so I cant access my .rprofile from the control panel.

My thought was I could just make a different library function, so I dont have to type a lib.loc statement every time i want to install/load a function. This is what i think the "liBerty" function should look like.

```
liBerty <- function(a) {
    require(a,lib.loc="C:\\Users\\bert\\Documents\\rpackages" )
}

liBerty(tm)
```

The error I am getting states "there is no package 'a'.". Is there a way i can write this function to accomplish my task?

The function needs to also be modified for installing packages

Comment: See the `character.only` argument in `?require`.

Comment: Or use `...`: `liBerty <- function(...) library(..., lib.loc = "C:\\Users\\bert\\Documents\\rpackages")`. This would also allow you to pass through other arguments as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.Bertages<-function(b){
     install.packages(b,lib="C:\\Users\\bert\\Documents\\rpackages")
}

liBerty<-function(a){
    require(a,lib.loc="C:\\Users\\bert\\Documents\\rpackages",   
        character.only=TRUE )
}

install.Bertages("lubridate")
liBerty("lubridate")
```